# Is there a way to make Matplotlib plot implicit polar equations?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Am trying to build a plotting platform that can handle a wide range of functions. For plotting polar equations I use MPLs built in "fig.add_subplot(polar=True)" for plotting. However, this will only work for equations of the form "r=.....". Is there a way to make MPL handle implicit polar equations like r^2+2*r = .....

Comment: Maybe [How to plot implicit functions of 3 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76115860/7758804)